# Angular Routing to Child path based on role

Tags: angular, canactivate, angular-guards, canactivatechild

After successful login, I redirect to following path
**this.router.navigate(['/main/'])**
Based on role received from login. Is it possible to redirect to diff modules.

**Example**: If Role is 'Admin' if I redirect to ['/main'] based on role it will navigate to admin module . Using guards

**Project structure:**

App module

```
---Login Module

---Main Module

    ---Admin Module

    ---User Module
```

Main Router File

````
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: ()=>import('./admin/admin.module').then(({
          AdminModule
        })=>AdminModule),
        canActivate: [
          RoleGuard
        ],
        data: {
          roles: [
            'Admin'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: ()=>import('./user/user.module').then(({
          UserModule
        })=>UserModule),
        canActivate: [
          RoleGuard
        ],
        data: {
          roles: [
            'User'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]```
````

Answer (score 1):

By use Guard you can do it;

Creat a Guard for Admin

```
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    const AdminTokenLogin = Math.random();
    if (AdminTokenLogin > 0.4) {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/admin']);
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/main']);
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

In your routes you can use;

```
{ path: 'admin/admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard] },
```